# UILabel object overlaps UITextfield in custom table cell after changing text property

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitextfield, uilabel

I have specified a custom cell containing a label and a text field in a nib file.

[image]

When I change the text property of the label and adding three of those cells in a section of a table view it looks like this:

[image]

When I don't touch the text property and simply adding the cell out of the nib file "as is" it looks like this

[image]

Well there still remains the question why the textfields right edge moved, but that is not the main problem. Can somebody tell me how I have to configure the label to avoid that nasty behavior when changing the labels text?

Comment: Did you try bringing the text field to front?

Comment: yeah I tried `[cell bringSubviewToFront:textField];` after changing the text property of the label with no effect. But I noticed that cell only has one subview. Shouldn't it have two?

Comment: Try `[cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:textField]` instead. You should always add subviews to `UITableViewCell`'s content view.

Comment: Are you changing the `text` property of the **additional** label or built-in label?

Comment: I finally found out what causes the problem: When you choose tag ids for your views in the nib file you should begin with 1 and not with 0. 0 means you don't want to tag this view, when you send a`viewWithTag:0` message, it will create a new view object and return this one...

Answer (score 0):

Change the frame of your `UILabels`. Now it looks like they are about 280-300px wide. Change it to something less, 120 for example.

```
yourTextField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 30);
```

or some other numbers. Play with it.

Hope it helps

P.S. some code would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Aaaah the great mysteries of autoresizingMask. Do it like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resize your labels width and can always change label background to clear

```
yourLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: hmm very strange, when i do that I get http://i.imgur.com/Wqya2.png   looks like I add a new label and not changing the existing one, but the only thing i do is getting the label with `[cell viewWithTag:]` and then setting the label text to some custom text...

Comment: so have you created your label in IB? if so change the background color to clear there.